# What is the best way to determine iOS 7 Safari user agent?

Tags: iphone, ios7

I'm having a styling issue that only exists in the iOS 7 versions of Safari.  I have been unable to determine how to detect if the user is on that device with CSS Media queries or what the exact user agents are for iOS 7 devices.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)
```

Comment: Is this any different for Chrome? How do I differentiate from any other browser running under iOS7?

Comment: @boost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106645/how-does-one-differentiate-between-chrome-and-safari-in-an-ios7-useragent-string

Answer (score 6):

IPhone/iOS7 user agent string looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
```