# How does one differentiate between Chrome and Safari in an iOS7 useragent string?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, ios7, user-agent

Useragent details are sketchy, or I'm not looking in the right places.

What, in terms of a `navigator.userAgent.match()`, would differentiate between Chrome and Safari on iOS7, iPad or iPhone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var matches = ua.match(/^.*(iPhone|iPad).*(OS\s[0-9]).*(CriOS|Version)\/[.0-9]*\sMobile.*$/i);
if (!matches) console.log("Not what we're looking for.");
else {
  console.log(matches[1]);
  if (matches[2] === 'OS 7') console.log(matches[2]);
  else console.log('Not the right version.');
  if (matches[3] === 'CriOS') console.log("Chrome");
  else console.log("Safari");
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent

Comment: This! Testing for "CriOS" worked for me. i'd neve have found this on my owne, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about iOS, never had a device, but under Windows Chrome has a `window.chrome` object defined. Check for it existence and if it's there - you're in Chrome.

If similar approach works under iOS (I think it should) then u don't need to check UserAgent.