# How to distunguish between Android and iOS on an app download page

Tags: android, ios

I have the following problem:

I'm offering an android and an ios app over a download page, which should automaticly select the right binary for the users platform.
Until now I'm parsing the UA-String to detect the platform, but I have many android users with Safari as standard browser which uses exactly the same UA-String like on iOS.

Is there any reliable way for an OS detection over a webpage?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_spoofing

Answer (score 2):

They do have different UA, just a quick google search:

http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings

http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/

Also, check my other answer:

[What is the best way to determine iOS 7 Safari user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012641/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-ios-7-safari-user-agent/19013065#19013065)